# Vimeo API returns inconsistent CDN URL

Tags: vimeo-api

We're using the Vimeo API for a client to play 3 different 360 videos through Android and iOS apps - in some cases we had to make some exceptions in our app to  work around special characters in the URL that were causing problems with our player - so we have some code to tidy up the final video URL.

This worked fine, at first, but now it seems as if the Vimeo API is returning different URLs for 2 out of 3 of our videos. Videos from fpdl.vimeocdn.com work fine.  They all used this domain when we first created the app. But two of our videos changed to gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net and have a different syntax.

Is this something we can't control? Will the CDN targets change often? Will all 3 of our videos eventually change to the new URL? Before we go back and adjust code again - I need to evaluate if we should just use a different player instead, if this will happen frequently.

Comment: Why don't you ask the Vimeo support about this? They should know the best answer for your problem

Comment: Vimeo support suggests developers using the API post in Stack Overflow and tag "vimeo-api". They respond here fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimeo uses different CDNs to host video files, and those CDNs should not matter to the viewer/enduser.

When getting the [direct video file links](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links) (either using the API or from the video's Settings page), those links are HTTP 302 redirect links to the actual video file resource. The location of that resource changes every few hours, so always make sure you use the redirect URL provided, and make sure the player being used supports redirects.

Comment: so it's not possible to get the final 302 redirect? tried using get_headers and getting 403 with 'Location' set to just vimeo.com

Comment: @dryan1144 No, the final redirect cannot be retrieved

Comment: I had problems once with gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net. I had to change my DNS to forward queries to avoid getting bad IP addresses from this name.